# switching image positions with javascript function

Tags: javascript, image, function

I have two images named sun.jpg and moon.jpg I need help completing this task.

•Use a function to swap the positions of the images when the mouse is over either image. (Call the same function in the onmouseover event handler for both images. The function will load images in the appropriate positions.)

•   Swap the images back to their original positions when the mouse is moved off of the images (You can use the same function and pass different values with the parameters. This function will load both of the original images.)

```
<script>
     function MouseRollover(MyImage) { 
          MyImage.src = "Rollover_Images/moon.jpg"; 
     } 
     function MouseOut(MyImage) { MyImage.src = "Rollover_Images/sun.jpg"; }
</script> 
<img src="Rollover_Images/sun.jpg" onMouseOver="MouseRollover(this)" onMouseOut="MouseOut(this)">
<img src="Rollover_Images/moon.jpg" onMouseOver="MouseOut(this)" onMouseOut="MouseRollover(this)">
```

Comment: write what you have tried so far

Comment: <script>function MouseRollover(MyImage) {
         MyImage.src = "Rollover_Images/moon.jpg";  }
                                                                                                      function MouseOut(MyImage) {
                MyImage.src = "Rollover_Images/sun.jpg";
    }
</script>                                                     <img src="Rollover_Images/sun.jpg" 
onMouseOver="MouseRollover(this)" 
onMouseOut="MouseOut(this)">

<img src="Rollover_Images/moon.jpg" 
onMouseOver="MouseOut(this)" 
onMouseOut="MouseRollover(this)">

Comment: this is switching pictures when I mouse over each one individually, but my task says when one is moused over both need to swap

Comment: Where's the Java function?

Answer (score 0):

This does what you are looking for:

```
<img id="img1" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" onMouseOver="doFlip(true)" onMouseOut="doFlip(false)">
<img id="img2" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" onMouseOver="doFlip(true)" onMouseOut="doFlip(false)">
<script>
    var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
    var img2 = document.getElementById("img2");
    var img1path = "http://placehold.it/300x300";
    var img2path = "http://placehold.it/200x200";
    function doFlip(isOn) {
        if (isOn) {
            img1.src = img2path;
            img2.src = img1path;
        } else {
            img1.src = img1path;
            img2.src = img2path;
        }
    }
</script>
```

See fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/xpmgnas1/

Comment: I copied this and of course put the proper image paths and now they show up but they don't flip at all.

Comment: Did you update the image path in all locations?  There are 4 places you would have to update, 2 in the HTML and 2 in the JavaScript (img1path=... and img2path=...).  As you can see in the fiddle, it works.  Ideally, you would alter things a bit so that you wouldn't have duplicate image paths, but that'll be the part of the homework that you do yourself. :)